# Not able to split the div for rows and columns

Tags: html, css, asp.net-mvc

[image: Screen shot for Div]

creating this application in MVC5 with bootstrap....

I have added div :

```
<div class="divFullWidth" style="margin:10px 0px 0px -15px; height:150px;background-color:grey;">
    <div class="wireframe_div">

        <div class="Row">
            <div class="Cell">
                @Html.Label("Ext :")
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="Row">
            <div class="Cell">
                @Html.TextBox("txt_Ext", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS :

```
  .wireframe_div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: darkgrey;
     padding: 15px 20px 25px 20px;
.Cell
    {
        display: table-cell;        
        padding-left: 5px;
        padding-right: 5px;

    }
.Row
    {
        display: table-row;
    }
  .divFullWidth { 
       float: left;
      width: 100%;

}
```

But am not able split the div exactly like in screen shot.

Can any one help on this. Am very new to web tech.

Comment: Plz put entire your html and css or create jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="width: 100%; height: 150px;">
        <div style=" width: 100%; height: 30%;">
        Ext <input type="text" style="width: 35%;"/>
        Area <input type="text"  style="width: 10%;"/>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 50%; height: 70%; float: left;  text-align: center;">
        Activity Catagory <input type="text" style="width: 80%;"/>
        </div>
        <div style="width: 50%; height: 70%; float: right;">
            <div style="width: 50%; height: 100%; float: right; text-align: center;">
                Activity Date To<input type="text" style="width: 80%;"/>
            </div>
            <div style="width: 50%; height: 100%; float: left;  text-align: center;">
            Activity Date From <input type="text" style="width: 80%;"/>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
```

also try bootstrap it makes life easy

Comment: thanks for your reply.. can you help with bootstrap.